# $_SESSION being ignored, creating if/else issue

Tags: php, session, comparison, if-statement

for some of my php pages, i use the $_SESSION to determine if a user is signed in, the code is:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['USERID'])&&$_SESSION['USERID']>=0&&is_numeric($_SESSION['USERID']));
```

for whatever reason, this if statement is being ignored, I have tested the $_SESSION to make sure that the value is empty by trying

```
$session=$_SESSION['USERID']; echo"$session"; the result is blank.
```

now at the end of php file i want to use an else follow the closing if bracket, this is creating the error of:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE
```

This is extremely frustrating, why would this occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a semicolon after your `if`. Take it out, and it won't be ignored, plus your `else` will work.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['USERID'])
   && $_SESSION['USERID'] >= 0
   && is_numeric($_SESSION['USERID']));
#-------------------------------------^ shouldn't be here.
```

Comment: oh my god, what a ridiculous mistake on my part, thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1):

That ; at the end of the statement looks highly suspicious. Don't you mean { there?